# Function name changed dynamically based on onchange id

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make a form, simple right? Not quite.

I currently have the form setup with two select boxes, the first select when changed using a onchange function runs a php page which generates the 2nd select box.

I then have another function that adds another 'instance' of the 2 select boxes so I can add multiple rows to the table at once without having to input one at a time.

The problem arises when I add more 'instances', the onchange function sees both the original and new 'instances' of the 2nd select box as the same one.

As I can see it my best bet is to dynamically name the function and the div containing the 2nd select box, which is where I'm stuck. My question is, how would I go about changing the 'showDim' function and 'dimdiv' div id so they match up?

js function to call Dim select box;

```
<script>
    function showDim(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("dimdiv").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("dimdiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_dim.php?id="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

html/php for the 1st select box and div containing 2nd select box; (the other function duplicates this part for as many times as I need)

```
<label>Style:</label>
    <select name='Style' id='Style' onchange="showDim(this.value)">
        <option value='0' class='red'>Select a style...</option>            
        <?php
            include ('connect.php');

            $getsty = $db->prepare("SELECT Style_ID, Style_Type FROM style ORDER BY Style_Type ASC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;"); 
            $getsty->execute();
                while($row = $getsty->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
                    $Style_ID = $row['Style_ID'];
                    $Style_Type = $row['Style_Type'];                   
                    echo "      <option value='$Style_ID'>$Style_Type</option>";
                }                                       
        ?>                          
<br>
<div id='txtHint2'>                 
    <label>Dimensions:</label>
        <select name='Dim'>
            <option value='0' class='red'>Select the dimensions...</option> 
        </select>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a totally different approach. I don't see where your element with ID `#dimdiv` is, but create a wrapper around your 'instance' to group them, including the `#dimdiv`. But all IDs now ought to be classes.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div class="instance">
    <label>Style:</label>
        <select name='Style' class='style' onchange="showDim(this)">
            <option value='0' class='red'>Select a style...</option>            
            <?php
                include ('connect.php');

                $getsty = $db->prepare("SELECT Style_ID, Style_Type FROM style ORDER BY Style_Type ASC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;"); 
                $getsty->execute();
                    while($row = $getsty->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
                        $Style_ID = $row['Style_ID'];
                        $Style_Type = $row['Style_Type'];                   
                        echo "      <option value='$Style_ID'>$Style_Type</option>";
                    }                                       
            ?>                          
    <!-- Note: for proper HTML markup, a non-container tag must be self-closing like the following br -->
    <br />
    <div class='txtHint2'>
        <label>Dimensions:</label>
            <select name='Dim'>
                <option value='0' class='red'>Select the dimensions...</option> 
            </select>           
    </div>
    <div class="dimdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously this will break your current code. You cannot use `document.getElementById('dimdiv')` to find the element whose *innerHTML* you want to set. So we need to revamp your code...

First step: We somehow need to know which group number the `showDim` function is invoked on. This is easiest done by not only passing the value of the element to the function, but the element itself. It allows us to use `document.getElementsByClassName('style')`*1 and compare each returned element with the current element.

The first match is the *instance group's index* which we can now use in a similar approach to extract the corresponding `.dimdiv` of the same group. So now we have found our target element without the need to create multiple instances of a single function, which is in my eyes flawed design... it junks up memory.

Your changed code could look like this:

*HTML*

```
<select name="Style" class="style" onchange="showDim(this)">
    ...
</select>
```

*JavaScript* (edited)

```
function showDim(elem)
{
    // Best would be to pack this code into a separate function.
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('style'),
        groupIndex = -1,
        targetDimDiv,
        i;
    for( i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i ) {
        if( elems[i] == elem ) {
            groupIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // This can only happen if somebody plays around with your function
    // manually calling it and providing an unexpected parameter.
    if( groupIndex == -1 )
    {
        return;
    }

    targetDimDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('dimdiv')[groupIndex];

    if (elem.value == "")
    {
        targetDimDiv.innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    // ...XMLHttpRequest...
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function( ) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
            targetDimDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    // ...send AJAX...
}
```

Finally I'd remark a last critical point: I don't think it's a good idea to create an ajax for each change of value. I think it's a better idea to already deliver the responses with the website and retrieve the information you need from there. It would save a lot more traffic afterall...

Sorry for the lengthy answer, but I believe it is important to really **understand** why code works the way it works. And I had the suspicion you might not be all that experienced... ;)

*1: I believe `document.getElementsByClassName` does not exist in older versions of IE. You could write a patch using `document.getElementsByTagName` matching classes manually if you have to support those versions.

P.S.: Haven't tested the code. It is only to provide you a generic guideline. The rest is up to you. Fiddle around with it to fit it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for all this effort, It's much appreciated. I'm having trouble testing it at the moment as the 2nd select box for the dimensions isn't being updated because the page get_dim.php isn't being called, I assume the 'send AJAX' part is where I would do this. I have tried useing the old `xmlhttp.open("GET","get_cust.php?id="+elem,true); xmlhttp.send();` but it doesnt work. Will I need this somewhere else in the function or am I just not understanding. Thanks (I plan on tearing this apart to understand it once its working for use in other projects)

Comment: Do you have any error messages for me? Do you register any outgoing traffic (in your developer tools)? If so, log the `xmlhttp.readyState` and `xmlhttp.status` properties in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function to confirm that the request was successful.

Comment: There is no outgoing traffic onchange of the 1st select box. for reference here is what is currently running with your suggested changes [link](http://elcu.herobo.com) and heres what i had running before [link](http://elcu.herobo.com/system-index.php)

Comment: @user2558771 Well of course, you have a TypeError in your console. My bad, I forgot to adapt that piece of code. Right there where you reset the innerHTML of the `dimdiv` element: `document.getElementById('dimdiv').innerHTML="";` obviously returns null for `#dimdiv` since we removed the ID and replaced it with class. I'll edit my answer. Please note that I forgot to change the `onchange` of your select to. It needs to be `onchange="showDim(this)"`

Comment: I've made the changes and in the console I'm getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: xmlhttp is not defined` on the line 65 `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {`

Comment: That's weird. There are no changes to the variable, so it should work. I'd need the code to help you out, preferrably on a live site so I can work with it myself.

Comment: I've tried to put the whole page in this jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/PvLN6/) I don't know how to get the javascript working in it though.

Comment: If that is exactly your code, of course it won't work... you didn't replace my little placeholders with the actual code. I omitted it in my answer for clarity's sake. Replace `// ...XmlHttpRequest...` with the code you use to create the XmlHttpRequest object and it should fix the ReferenceError.

Comment: Ah! I thought they were just comments saying what it did, sorry. I have it working perfectly (I hope) now, Thanks. I'll now try to figure out exactly its all doing.

Comment: Well, I guess I should have pointed it out to avoid any ambiguity. But glad it's finally working. :)